# elasticsearch aggregation on object or key value pair

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

i have documents like this

document-1

```
{
  "edges" :[
    {
      "start" : "abc", 
      "end" : "def"
    },
    {
      "start" : "bbb", 
      "end" : "ccc"
    },
    {
      "start" : "xyz", 
      "end" : "aaa"
    }
  ]
}
```

document-2

```
{
  "edges" :[
    {
      "start" : "abc", 
      "end" : "def"
    },
    {
      "start" : "bbb", 
      "end" : "ccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get unique combinations of `start` and `end`.
ie, as follows

```
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": {
        "start": "abc",
        "end": "def"
      },
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": {
        "start": "bbb",
        "end": "ccc"
      },
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": {
        "start": "xyz",
        "end": "aaa"
      },
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried terms aggregations on the `start` and `end` field. but didn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to work with the `nested` datatype since arrays are flattened as it is very well described in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). This is the reason why you can't get the expected results as the relation between `key`and `value` is lost. Furthermore, you'll then need to add a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) aggregation on `edges`, where you can then apply the `terms` aggregations.
The hierarchy of the aggregations should look as follows:

```
nested: edge
    terms: key
        terms: value
```

Based on this, you can then produce the expected results by combining the results of the the terms aggregations.